# XNA windows phone release black textures

Tags: c#, windows-phone-7, xna, windows-phone, textures

i just made a 3d game in XNA for windows phone 7. I build it in release mode on visual studio 2010 and suddenly when I run game there is no textures on models - 2 models are black and one is transparent. Models are in .X format exported from 3dsmax and have textures in .jpg also added to game content. I set build action to none and all worked fine in debug mode. When I change to release mode - black textures. When I set build action to compile it gives me warning:

Asset was built 2 times with different settings:
using TextureImporter and TextureProcessor
using TextureImporter and TextureProcessor, referenced by...

and still no textures.

What can I do?

Comment: See if your debug and release mode resources differ, it might tell you if the problem is with your models and textures or something else.

Comment: How did you set the property "Build Action" - "Copy to Output Directory" property from the window textures "jpg" ?

Answer (score 0):

It sounds like your using a custom content processor to build out your assets.

Double check your textures to make sure that they are being built by your custom content processor and not the XNA one for your release build.